# How can I edit the settings tab from my android application?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an app and I want to know how can I edit the settings tab from my app. I want to add for example an About us page and a Share page. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Read documentation on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main.xml make different menu items..ie

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="SKIP"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

thats it........

Comment: for for callback........@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
 {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {        
       case android.R.id.home:            
        finish();
     onBackPressed();          
          return true;   
       case R.id.action_search: 
        
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dffds", 2000).show();            
           return true;  
       default:            
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
    }
 }